# Abstracting repetitive addEventListener('click'... functions to optimize code

Tags: javascript, css, html

EDIT: Looking for a non-Jquery Answer

As it stands this code is incredibly long for how simple it is. The only difference between specific instances is a number indicating the ID of the target. Is there a way to accomplish the same result with a single function that gets fed variable based on which div is clicked?

```
var $ = Sizzle,
p0 = $("#p0")[0];
p1 = $("#p1")[0];
p2 = $("#p2")[0];
p3 = $("#p3")[0];
p4 = $("#p4")[0];
p5 = $("#p5")[0];
p6 = $("#p6")[0];
p7 = $("#p7")[0];
lp0 = $("#productMenu li")[0];
lp1 = $("#productMenu li")[1];
lp2 = $("#productMenu li")[2];
lp3 = $("#productMenu li")[3];
lp4 = $("#productMenu li")[4];
lp5 = $("#productMenu li")[5];
lp6 = $("#productMenu li")[6];
lp7 = $("#productMenu li")[7];


lp0.addEventListener('click',open0,false);
lp1.addEventListener('click',open1,false);
lp2.addEventListener('click',open2,false);
lp3.addEventListener('click',open3,false);
lp4.addEventListener('click',open4,false);
lp5.addEventListener('click',open5,false);
lp6.addEventListener('click',open6,false);
lp7.addEventListener('click',open7,false);



function open0(){
p0.classList.toggle('off');
}

function open1(){
p1.classList.toggle('off');
}
function open2(){
p2.classList.toggle('off');
}

function open3(){
p3.classList.toggle('off');
}
function open4(){
p4.classList.toggle('off');
}

function open5(){
p5.classList.toggle('off');
}
function open6(){
p6.classList.toggle('off');
}

function open7(){
p7.classList.toggle('off');
}
```

Comment: Can you add a single event listener on a parent element?

Comment: Why are you using a jQuery selector and then retrieving the DOM node (instead of just using `document.getElementById()`) and then using `addEventListener()` rather than staying with jQuery's event-handling?

Comment: @DavidThomas because I'm not using jQuery, sorry I'm using Sizzle... I'll put that in the example

Comment: @StephenThomas That's an interesting idea to start, I'll look into it

Comment: Thanks, that does clarify things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$('#productMenu li').on('click', function () {
  var index = $("#productMenu li").index($(this));
  $('#p' + index).toggleClass('off');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, I'm looking for a non-Jquery answer

Answer (score 0):

In plain script, something like the following should work:

```
// Helper to convert a list to an array
function toArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=list.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    array[i] = list[i];
  }
  return array;
}

// Helper to add a listener without closure
function addFunction(source, target) {
  source.addEventListener('click', function(){target.classList.toggle('off')}, false);  
}

function addListeners() {
  var nodes = [];

  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {
    pNodes.push(document.getElementById('p' + i));
  }

  var lpNodes = toArray(document.getElementById('productMenu').getElementsByTagName('li'));

  for (var j=0, jLen=lpNodes.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    addFunction(lpNodes[j],pNodes[j]); 
  }
}
```

Untested of course, but the approach should help. It isn't really necessary to convert the NodeList returned by *getElementsByTagName* to an array, but it may be help performance.

There are other approaches to this, most obviously to use event delegation and put a single listener on a parent element (an UL?) that sees where the click came from, then toggles the related element if required. e.g. if the click came from lp0, toggle p0 (though you should probaby be using classes for this, not IDs).

Something like:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  var element;
  var target = event.target;

  if (target.tagName && target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'li') {
    var id = target.id.match(/\d+/$);

    if (id) {
      element = document.getElementById('p' + id[0]);
    }

    if (element) {
      element.classList.toggle('off');
    }
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('productMenu').addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
}
```